# Unsupported operand type for float and numpy.ufunc

Tags: numpy, operands

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
ClusterData['Bmag'] =   (-2.5*np.log10*0.088151)              # <<<<
ClusterData['Vmag'] =   (-2.5*np.log10*0.076521)              # <<<<
ClusterData['B_V']  =   (Bmag-Vmag)               # <<<<
# print(ClusterData)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'numpy.ufunc'

Comment: `np.log10` is a a function; what's it supposed to be?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html

Comment: Like @hpaulj said: You're multiplying a `float` with a function reference. Use `np.log10(value)` instead and be sure that you understand yourself what operations you are wanting to execute...

Comment: Thank you that fixed it